# Get maximum value and all corresponding details in nested join or similar when there are multiple matches

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, m

I have recently started using power query and have come across a small hurdle which I hope can be resolved quite easily

I have two tables. I bring values from the second table into the first table using outer kind type nestedjoining.

This seems to have the desired result, except when there are multiple matches in table 2. What I am seeing is that table 1 values then get duplicated and rows from table2 are matched with the duplicate rows.

I want to get the maximum row / limit it to the latest row only. I am looking for a relatively elegant solution. The best I have come up with so far is using some group by aggregate and max to display the values, however this is now giving me the maximum value which is duplicated over several rows as opposed to unique values. I could in theory group this again and be left with unique but wondering if there is out of the box solution.

```
  a                   b                                                          
  data1.1.1           data1.1.2                                                  
  data1.2.1           data1.2.2                                                  

  After nestedJoin:                                                              

  a                   b           c     d             e             f            
  data1.1.1           data1.1.2   298   data2.298.1   data2.298.2   data2.298.3  
  data1.1.1           data1.1.2   300   data2.300.1   data2.300.2   data2.300.3  
  data1.2.1           data1.2.2   500   data2.500.1   data2.500.2   data2.500.3  

  Desired Result:                                                                

  a                   b           c     d             e             f            
  data1.1.1           data1.1.2   300   data2.300.1   data2.300.2   data2.300.3  
  data1.2.1           data1.2.2   500   data2.500.1   data2.500.2   data2.500.3
```

```
let     
Source = Table.NestedJoin(Table1, {"a", "b"}, Table2, {"a", "b"}, "Table2", JoinKind.LeftOuter),     
#"Expanded GV" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Source, "Table2", {"e", "f", "g", }, {"Table2.e", "Table2.f","Table2.g"}),     
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each ([#"a"] <> null)) 
in
#"Filtered Rows"
```

Comment: The data in your `After nestedJoin`  table does not appear in your first table(s).  Also, please provide the code you are using. But probably you just group your result and pull out the highest value for c.

Comment: I skipped the steps where I nestjoin and then expand table to get the relevant fields I am looking for. The first table is just Table1, I haven't shown Table2 here. Grouping again and getting max value seems simple enough, however how do I retain or show the values of the "maximum" row

Comment: Examining the data you supply, you can groupBy all the columns except column C

Comment: if i group by all columns except C will i not be left with the values of the rows I do not need?

Comment: Not given your data.  You select all the columns except C.  Then, when you choose the aggregation operation, choose Max on column C.

Comment: columns d to e are columns brought in by Table2 so if i group all except C i will be left with duplicate rows as the values in there are distinct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon re-reading, I think my comments as to the methodology were not clear.  I should have written to group the columns based on `a` and `b` but don't aggregate. Then extract the row with the `max` in column `c`.
Here is code that changes your `After nestedJoin` (`Table1` in my workbook) to your `Desired Results`.  I think this is what you are looking for.

The steps are all done from the Power Query UI, and the formula for the added column is:  `=Table.Max([Grouped],"c")`

#### M Code

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"a", type text}, {"b", type text}, {"c", Int64.Type}, {"d", type text}, {"e", type text}, {"f", type text}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"a", "b"}, {{"Grouped", each _, type table [a=text, b=text, c=number, d=text, e=text, f=text]}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each Table.Max([Grouped],"c")),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom", {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"}, {"a.1", "b.1", "c", "d", "e", "f"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Custom",{"a", "b", "Grouped"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"a.1", "a"}, {"b.1", "b"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```

[image]

Comment: This seems more like it, and I managed to take this approach which in preview mode seems to do the job, however when loading the rows, it takes a really big performance hit. To put it in context, with Table.Max the refresh has been running for over 20 minutes now. So i gave up and implemented using grouping max with All rows and then removing duplicated later. This was accomplished in ~10sec. Table 1 has ~6k rows and Table 2 has ~ 1k rows. I suspect Table.Max is reloading all the rows of Table2 6k times hence the performance hit. I will do write up later of how i achieved it.